# Google Drive File/sheet API : file not found when I try to copy

Tags: php, api, file, copy

Here is the URL of the API I Call, to copy a file from Google Drive File API :

[https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/1GWBfT2gApqaeZ2JRjmNID0BlEs_okMg9/copy?convert=true&supportsAllDrives=true&supportsTeamDrives=true&access_token=[my](https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/1GWBfT2gApqaeZ2JRjmNID0BlEs_okMg9/copy?convert=true&supportsAllDrives=true&supportsTeamDrives=true&access_token=%5Bmy) token]

it return "**Not Found**".

If I try it directly from Google API reference, it works, the file is copied :
https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/copy

If I try it with v.3, and I remove the 'convert=true' parameter, still got 'Not Found'.

If I try the same API with the same file ID, without the 'copy' method (and without the 'convert param), it work, I got the file, in both V3 and V2  :
[https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/1GWBfT2gApqaeZ2JRjmNID0BlEs_okMg9/?supportsAllDrives=true&supportsTeamDrives=true&access_token=[my](https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/1GWBfT2gApqaeZ2JRjmNID0BlEs_okMg9/?supportsAllDrives=true&supportsTeamDrives=true&access_token=%5Bmy) token]

here are the scopes I have set (in PHP Google API client) :

- Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE_FILE
- Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE
- Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE_APPDATA
- Google_Service_Sheets::SPREADSHEETS Google_Service_Sheets::DRIVE
- Google_Service_Sheets::DRIVE_FILE

thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the error...

I had to set the  custom request 'POST'  into the header in the cUrl  :
PHP :
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');